# Why are login fields mostly right-aligned?

Tags: web, user-interface

> Most popular web-sites that require you to log in, have the authentication form on the right side of the page. More or less. As a right-handed person, I find it rather intuitive to look at and convenient to work with—that I don't have to sprain my neck or move my mouse too much to select the username field (though of late, most pages do that by default, immediately after loading completes). Not being omniscient I wonder how a left-handed person would react to the very same UI. Which begs the question: should this not be part of the web-site design goal to flip the forms for a left-handed person? Also, I guess it matters what language you are interacting in. For a language like English that reads left to right, having the form on your right probably makes more sense.

Some examples to look at with different layout of auth forms:

> Facebook, Gmail, Y!   **Right**
>   Buzzword              **Center**
>   SOF                   **Left**

Feel free to share your $0.02. **I'd also be interested to know if actual research has gone in to this.**

**Update:(02/20)** Some excellent posts there. Good time to summarize:

**The story so far:**

- Most web-pages are static in terms of manoeuvrability.
- Users have little/no choice on how content is served.
- English being a the lingua franca of the Internet, 
  web sites have, over time ended up using the left-to-right
  reading order of English as *the* order. This is in
  keeping with UI design guidelines.
- Being left-handed puts you at unease when using such web-sites
  (not a general rule perhaps, but people have experienced issues)
- Users tend to change habits rather than complain.

***Clarification:** Some of you seem to have misinterpreted my reference to mouse manoeuvre. It was supposed to serve as an example of what I think I'd take time to get adjusted to if things weren't the way they are. Cheers!*

Comment: I think you mean "left-to-right reading order of English."

Comment: What's amusing is that Asian scripting were adapted to the English layout: they are originally written right-to-left in columns, but on computers they are written in lines, left-to-right. Arabic and Hebrew are examples of languages that didn't underwent this change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i'm left-handed.  even more, i'm the only one i know that uses mouse on the left and swaps buttons (so the 'main' button is my index).  but i don't see why you think that anything on screen should move 'for our benefit'.

one thing i've found by obsessively observing (i did my first semi-formal poll about this when i was 13 years old) other left-handed people's habits is that there's a lot more variety among us than among right-handed people.  so, if you want to do some 'multi-handed' ergonomics, you shouldn't assume anything, just allow for maximum flexibility.

Comment: That answers another question: Whether you'd even want to have the form swapped. Thanks!

Comment: I used to swap the buttons but when I worked as a computer tech 4 years I at some point stopped.  Mousing got a bit confusing.  I figured it was easier just to learn the right button config, and move the mouse over to the left side. I've found many applications aren't conducive to being left-handed.

Comment: I used to move the mouse over to the left side and swap the buttons every time I sat down in my college computer lab, but eventually I just gave up and started using the mouse right-handed.

Comment: @joel/Cj: of course i don't swap other people's mice buttons either! i was talking about my own machine.  i found very weird that other left-handed people don't do this, most i know don't even move their own mouse to the left side!

Comment: That speaks volumes about the sorry state of interaction design. Very, very interesting inputs -- thank you Cj and Joel! Whoever said tools are meant to help us :P

Comment: I'm right-handed, but I still use the mouse left-handed and swap the buttons.  Left-click is always the index finger, no matter which hand you're using.  I learned to use the mouse left-handed when I worked as a drafter.  Since the number pad is always on the right side of the keyboard, I could mouse left-handed and enter numbers right-handed.  It made me about 15 to 20% more efficient than my single-handed coworkers.

Comment: @Stewbob: that's the same reason why i liked the old PC keyboard with function keys on the left side.  Before the mouse arrived to PCs, it was the only use for the left hand.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it has anything to do with what's natural. At least not anymore. Whatever the original reason, it's self-perpetuating now. Most websites have the login form on the right-hand side of the page. Therefore, if you're striving for the goal of "don't make me think," you should put the login form on the right-hand side of the page...

...thus increasing the number of sites that have the login form on the right-hand side of the page and the strength of the suggestion to put the login form on the right-hand side of the page so your users won't have to think...

...thus increasing... you get the idea.

Comment: That was my idea, but I am wondering if there has been some research on this. I'd be interested however contrary the results might be to my belief.

Comment: And guess how different life would have been if the Internet started off in Hebrew or Arabic

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess the reason for sticking it in the upper-right corner is that it's an important thing to do on a page, but not nearly as important as the title for the page/website, and that goes in the top-left corner.  It's all about reading order.

I doubt right-handedness or left-handedness makes any difference.  Your hand and neck use independent muscle groups.

Answer (score 2):

UI Design 101 dictates that you orient the controls of your user interface (desktop application, web page, etc.) using the natural reading order of your customers.  For English users, this would entail a left-to-right, top-to-bottom approach.  That is, the most important information should be in the top-left corner and the least important information should be in the bottom-right corner.

The reason various websites put their login controls at different locations has less to do with conformance with some industry standard than it does with what the website designers perceive to be the most important information.

Take Gmail for example.  Google is more concerned with advertising their various products (Gmail, Web History, iGoogle, etc.) to new users than they are about you logging in.  Hence, they tout their products in the place that most users look first - the top-left corner.  If you've already got an account, you immediately skip over this and type your login credentials on the right-hand side.  And remember that once you're logged in, you never see this screen again.  With this approach, Google is clearly trying to accommodate new users, not existing users.  From a business perspective, this makes sense.

Comment: Can you clarify 'natural reading order of your customers'? Does this mean that we should adhere to the reading order of the user's mother tongue (for example) instead of the reading order of the language in which content is served?

Comment: Good point.  In most cases, the 'natural reading order' should apply to the language in which the content is presented.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this page](http://www.onlinecontentguide.co.uk/written-content/page-layout-size.html) interesting.

"As the owner of a website you want people to be able to use your website easily and reach content quickly - which is your ultimate goal. Being consistent with other websites in terms of the positioning of menus and content will help your visitors, give them a better overall experience and reduce the likelihood of closing the browser in annoyance. Once you have confirmed the layout, you can by all means go wild with the content and design."

Having the login box on the right side also allows you to keep the left hand navigation bar the same for people who are logged in and those who are not.  See ING Direct's website for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the link. There's a whole field dedicated to this sort of thing -- interaction architecture. See http://www.interactionarchitect.com/en/articles.htm.

Comment: However, the sites I had in mind do not reuse the right-side panel content (there isn't much to begin with).

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000061.html) by Joel very enlightening. The part about conforming with the leaders in your field in order to eschew confusion and frustration is particularly applicable to your question.

Comment: Thanks! Read that just now. IMO, he's pressing about behavior consistency. I am talking about intuitive UI.

Comment: Addendum: They are different, though not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

I am left handed but I use the mouse with my right hand, always have....I feel awkward when I use it with my left now.

Comment: Curious. I wish I was equally ambidextrous!

Comment: I Don't consider myself ambidextrous, I use different hands for different things (left for writing, drawing). The only thing I can actually use either hand for is scissors.

Answer (score 0):

I'd never really thought about this before...  interesting.  I think it has to do with organization for an left-to-right language universe.

Since most languages move from left-to-right, it makes sense to have the site expand from the left to the right.  Along those same lines, if you need to expand your menus, it makes sense to expand your menus from the left out to the right.  However, user links (such as login, profile, etc.) are typically static.  If you want to keep them out of the way of the rest of your navigation, better to put them on the other corner of the page - thus the right corner, rather than the left.

Edit: Sorry, I think I misinterpreted your question to mean "why are the login links on the upper right" rather than "why is the whole form on the right side of the page".

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert in design, but I have my opinion about this subject.

The main reason there is alignment on the right should have to do with the way of reading. The majority of existing languages. The most people don't care about the minority of people, they only care about the majority.

> Not being omniscient I wonder how a left-handed person would react to the very same UI

I don't think that this could matters for any person. But I'm not the right kind of guy to talk about this... I write with right hand :S

It would be great that all companies start to worry about this subject, for a better world :D

---

### It's choice, not chance, that determines your destiny.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how it matters which hand you use the mouse with (FWIW, I am right-handed but use the mouse with my left hand).

Which hand you use does not alter where your cursor rests on the screen, so you don't have to move it any further with one hand than with the other.  The distance is the same - i.e. however far it is from the last thing you clicked on.